# PHP cURL fails to fetch images from website

Tags: php, curl

I've written a small PHP script for grabbing images with curl and saving them locally.
It reads the urls for the images from my db, grabs it and saves the file to a folder.
Tested and works on a couple other websites before, fails with a new one I'm trying it with.
I did some reading around, modified the script a bit but still nothing.

Please suggest what to look out for.

```
$query_products = "SELECT * from product";
$products = mysql_query($query_products, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products);
$totalRows_products = mysql_num_rows($products);

do {
    $ch = curl_init ($row_products['picture']);
    $agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/4.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

    $rawdata = curl_exec ($ch);
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if($http_status==200){ 
        $fp = fopen("images/products/".$row_products['productcode'].".jpg", 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
        fclose($fp);
        echo ' -- Downloaded <a href="'.$row_products['picture'].'" target="_blank">'.$newname.'</a> to local: <a href="images/products/'.$newname.'" target="_blank">'.$newname.'</a>';
    } else {
        echo ' -- Failed to download <a href="'.$row_products['picture'].'" target="_blank">'.$row_products['picture'].'</a>';  
    }

    usleep(500);
} while ($row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products));
```

Comment: Status should be 200 for a success, not zero. Run `curl_getinfo()` without a second arg to see what you're getting back.

Comment: Based on what @AlexHowansky said, it would be interesting to print out `$http_status`, there's some info regarding the meaning of many http result codes [on the curl_info manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) - you could be chasing a problem as trivial as a 403 - Forbidden response.

Comment: I mistakenly left the zero there, I was playing around with all kinds of response codes. The response code is 400.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: This is the result of curl_getinfo() `Array ( [url] => http://www.somedomain.com/path/A230.20013-200.JPG [content_type] => text/html; charset=us-ascii [http_code] => 400 [header_size] => 179 [request_size] => 216 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.063 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0.002 [pretransfer_time] => 0.002 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 311 [speed_download] => 4936 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 311 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.063 [redirect_time] => 0 ) `

Comment: Interesting, you ask for a JPG and it returns a `text/html` measuring 311 bytes.  Printing that output text should tell  you what's going on (there are many ways to protect media from being leeched off a site, you could have hit one of these).

Comment: Isn't it strange that if I open http://www.somedomain.com/path/A230.20013-200.JPG in my browser it opens right away? Perhaps it has to do with one of the options i'm setting with curl_setopt?

Comment: @bikey77 presence of a cookie or valid authentication maybe?  What does the server return in the text/html response you mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 1):

Your target website may require/check a combination of things. In order:

- Location. Some websites only allow the referer to be a certain value (either their site or no referer, to prevent hotlinking)
- Incorrect URL
- Cookies. Yes, this can be checked
- Authentication of some sort

The only way to do this is to sniff what a normal request looks like and to mimic it. Your `MSIE` user-agent string looks different from a genuine MSIE UA, however, and I'd consider changing it to an exact copy of a real one if I were you.

Could you get curl to output to a file (using the setopt for output stream) and telling us what error code you are getting, along with the URL of an image? This will help me be more precise.

Also, 0 isn't a success - it's a failure

Comment: The images URL's come from a supplier and are meant to be used from other websites. I can view the image properly in my browser if I enter the URL, so I dont think it's a matter of authentication or access rights. I simply prefer to save them locally so that I can handle them better (ex. cache them) rather than requesting them from the supplier's website each time.